# Flutter Google Maps Dynamically zoom in and out with radius circle

Tags: google-maps, flutter

In the [google map](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) I have a radius circle. This Circle can be made smaller and larger by clicking on the buttons.

My code just doesn't work properly because as soon as I make the circle bigger, the zoom gets closer. As soon as I make the circle smaller, it zooms out further.

The buttons then invoke this function:

```
 void addRadiusToMap(radius, location) {
    setState(() {
      double reciprocal(double d) => 1 * d;
      circle.clear();
      circle.add(Circle(
        circleId: CircleId("1"),
        center: location,
        radius: reciprocal(radius.toDouble()),
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fillColor: Color.fromARGB(102, 51, 153, 5)
      ));
      mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
          CameraPosition(target: location, zoom: radius/71)));
    });
  }
```

After which this rule controls the zooming in and out:

```
mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(target: location, zoom: radius/71)));
```

Here I divide the radius by 71 to get a normal zoom number, but as soon as the radius gets bigger the answer will get bigger and the zoom will be zoomed in. Anyone have a different solution for this?

Comment: Bigger zooms are closer in (0 is the whole world), you want to increase the zoom level as you decrease the radius of the circle.  Better to zoom to the bounds of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 double zoomLevel = 11;
      if (circle != null) {
        double radius = _circleRadius + _circleRadius / 2;
        double scale = radius / 400;
        zoomLevel = (16 - scale / 2);
      }
```